# SourceKit Plugins

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dropbox, sourcekit

I've been playing with [SourceKit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iieeldjdihkpoapgipfkeoddjckopgjg), which is an awesome Chrome app for editing your Dropbox files using the [Ajax.org Code Editor](http://ace.ajax.org/). In the release notes for version 0.5 and the readme, the author says

> Arbitrary Javascript "plugins" are loaded post initialization from your Dropbox account. It is loaded from /.sourcekit/plugins/"

I've tried putting some Javascript in that directory, but can't seem to get anything to execute. Does anyone know of documentation for or examples of SourceKit plugins?

(I've submitted an [issue on the GitHub project](https://github.com/kenotron/sourcekit/issues/issue/45), but have gotten no response.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SourceKit dev here. Forget about the old styled plugins that I was referring to in the old README CHANGELOG entry. I switched internally to use Dojo, Ace and Require JS. I haven't gotten to the point of adding plugin support just yet with this new rewrite...

It'll come in due time! In the meantime, if you have any ideas, I do take in pull requests via github: http://www.github.com/kenotron/sourcekit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [these plugins for Bespin at Mozilla Labs](http://bespinplugins.mozillalabs.com/plugins) should fit the bill but they don't seem to function at all at the moment. This ["plugin_manager.js" file](https://github.com/joewalker/pilot/blob/master/lib/pilot/plugin_manager.js) from [the pilot library](https://github.com/joewalker/pilot) looks like it does just that for the SourceKit project and it was/is the same deal for Bespin/Skywriter/ACE.

I don't think at this stage there are any "downloadable" plugins for SourceKit, but the plugins in the Bespin Gallery might be worth hacking at.